# update section of php file using a php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a piece of code which is working and all okay. to use this code I have manually gone into a php file, found the right section and copied my code into the right area of the existing file.

I would like to create a sort of install script for my code.

It would ideally do the following:

copy the existing file and rename it (got my code to do this)

```
$file = 'example.txt';
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak';
if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
```

Then add either my code chunk or a php include of a file with my code chunk within it to a certain part of the existing php file.

Is this possible and how would it be done? I don't mind if it is done by php or ajax. it is for a wp plugin.

I currently have the check if another plugin is installed and I have the copy and rename part done but need this part doing.

Comment: Why not put an `include` in there permanently that points to your custom code? If there's a condition to select different files to include, put the conditional logic in place to point to the right file, then have the `include` load said file.

Comment: I am trying to update a file from another plugin so cannot include something permanently because the file I am trying to edit isn't part of my plugin.

Comment: Why not fork the other plugin and maintain the fork?

Comment: How would I go about this as the original plugin I would like to add functionality to is woocommerce?

Comment: Put it under version control and start hacking ;) new plugin could be bhwd-woocommerce, haha.

Comment: haha this is gunna sound really stupid but this is the first time i have done a plugin etc... what do you mean by version control? noob moment

Comment: Nice, well do what you must, but I highly recommend spending some time ramping up on [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). I'll also throw in my 2 cents and suggest [git](http://git-scm.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to put your include at the top, or you could search on something at the position you want and replace that:

```
if(file_exists($file)) {
    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    $content = str_replace("<?php", "<?php\ninclude('yourfile.php');\n", $content);
    file_put_contents($file, $content);
}
```

I'm not a fan of WordPress and don't know it, but there should be some hooks or something to let the plugins use each other, as this is very hackish.